# How do I upgrade to Istio 1.1.3 on GKE using the Istio add-on?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#supported_gke_cluster_versions) on Google Cloud's website, the supported GKE version for Istio 1.1.3 is `1.13.5-gke.15`.

However, even a fresh GKE install using the `$ gcloud beta container clusters create ... --cluster-version "1.13.5-gke.15" ...` command gets the following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Master version "1.13.5-gke.15" is unsupported.`.

According to the [GKE release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#may_13_2019), `v1.12.7-gke.17` of GKE should "Upgrade Istio to 1.1.3" (the first bullet point). However, it still had version `1.0.6-gke.3`.

You can easily find the version installed on GKE using the following command:

```sh
$ kubectl get deployment istio-pilot -o yaml -n istio-system | grep image: | cut -d ':' -f3 | head -1
1.0.6-gke.3
```

**How do I get the GKE Istio add-on version 1.1.3 installed on my cluster?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That GKE version is still in alpha, so you need to pass the `--enable-kubernetes-alpha` flag. Also, you don't need to use `gcloud alpha`.

e.g. try the following:

```
gcloud container clusters create mycluster --enable-kubernetes-alpha \
  --zone us-central1-c --cluster-version=1.13.5-gke.15
```

See also the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster#alpha) on installing alpha clusters.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see GKE's [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes) for V1.12.X have been recently corrected, stating that:

> 'Istio was not upgraded to 1.1.3 in v1.12.7-gke.17.'

I think it make sense to stick to OSS version of Istio for now, if you want to use a more recent versions than 1.0.6, or switch to gke`s alpha version as @David Ebbo suggested.